# Why does a mysqli connection forward me to some random host on some computers but not others?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, mysqli

I have a PHP script that takes input from the user and then connects them to a database.
It takes the data in fine, but then an unexpected thing occurs on some computers:
it forwards me to a random host that was not entered anywhere.
This happens on my Win10 machine, but not on a Win7 machine that is in the same building.
The original host I enter looks something like this: `db2041615326.hosting-data.io` but it forwards me to this host: `infongp-us92.perfora.net`
Here is a basic version of my code:

```php
<?php
if (!$_POST){
    echo "No Form was submitted!!!";
?>

<form action="db_login.php" method="post">
    Host Name: <input type="text" name="host_name">
    Database: <input type="text" name="database">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php }else{ ?>
<?php
$database = $_POST['database'];
$host_name = $_POST['host_name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$link = new mysqli($host_name, $username, $password, $database);
if ($link->connect_error) {
    die('<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: '. $link->connect_error .'</p>'.'<br>Check all information carefully...');
}else{
# echo "Connection Successful";
# Here code sets cookies with encoded info(db, host, username, password)
header("Location: dashboard.php");
}
```

Note: this is hosted with IONOS.
Edit:
If I manually encode the information and then import it into cookies, the connection works and doesn't forward me to this weird host.

Comment: I'd suggest testing the DNS lookup using [dig](https://help.dyn.com/how-to-use-binds-dig-tool/) and see if the host you intended to use is being mapped to the other one. Perhaps your DNS server is compromised, or there's a man-in-the-middle attack affecting the result.

Comment: Off-topic, it's a terrible idea from a security perspective to develop an open MySQL relay as you're doing. Please don't do that.

Comment: what do you mean? The database I'm connecting to is a sandbox

Comment: But anyone who can call your script can use it to connect to _any_ database on any server.

Comment: Yes, But the next page it forwards you to will fail, because it's designed for one database

Comment: You show no forwarding code. Besides, PHP can't share a database connection between requests. It makes no sense to connect to the database and then forward to another PHP page.

Comment: The connection is to ensure that the info entered is functional, as for the forward, Il edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. Probably. I think when copying the hostname from  a txt file, I took the "\n" at the end... so the hostname went crazy and forwarded me